# How can I use regex to match strings if the regex has nested group?

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching

There are some strings:

```
111/aaa
111/aaa|222/bbb
```

They are in the form of expression:

```
(.*)/(.*)(|(.*)/(.*))?
```

I tried to use it to match a string and extract the values:

```
var rrr = """(.*)/(.*)(|(.*)/(.*))?""".r

"123/aaa|444/bbb" match {
    case rrr(pid,pname, cid,cname) => println(s"$pid, $pname, $cid, $cname")
    case _ => println("not matched ?!")
}
```

But it prints:

```
not matched ?!
```

And I want to get:

```
123, aaa, 444, bbb
```

How to fix it?

---

UPDATE

Thanks for @BartKiers and @Barmar's anser, that I found my regex has several mistakes, and finally found this solution:

```
var rrr = """(.*?)/(.*?)([|](.*?)/(.*?))?""".r

"123/aaa|444/bbb" match {
    case rrr(pid,pname, _, cid,cname) => println(s"$pid, $pname, $cid, $cname")
    case _ => println("not matched ?!")
}
```

It works, but you can see there is a `_` which is actually not useful. Is there any way to redefine the regex that I can just write `rrr(pid,pname,cid,cname)` to match it?

Comment: `|` is a special character in regexp, you need to escape it.

Comment: I think I can use non-capture group: `?:`

Comment: Yes, if there are groups that you use just for the pattern, not to capture, that's what non-capture groups are for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.*` could lead to a lot of backtracking becuase `.*` would first match the complete string and then go back one by one until it matches the first `/`.

Also it won't capture the values in groups properly as you would expect it to..

You should use `.*?`

Your regex should be

```
^(.*?)/(.*?)(?:\|(.*?)/(.*?))?$
```

There wouldn't be any performance difference for small strings but it would capture the values in the right group

Notice the `?:` in the regex, it means don't capture the group `(?:\|(.*?)/(.*?))?`. So it will be 4 subgroups only as the result.

Answer (score 3):

Try to escape the `|`, which is the logical OR in regex:

```
var rrr = """(.*)/(.*)(\|(.*)/(.*))?""".r
```